# How to merge two image in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: image, xamarin, image-processing, xamarin.forms, zxing

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms iOS app. In the xaml file, there is a grid.

```
<Grid x:Name="QrCodeSite" HeightRequest="300" Margin="37, 37, 37, 0">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
<RowDefinition Height="*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

In the related .cs file, I use `ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms` to generate a QR code and place it in the grid. And I put my logo in the same grid, which will finally appear at the center of the QR code.

```
var barcode = new ZXingBarcodeImageView
{
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
barcode.BarcodeFormat = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Width = 650;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Height = 650;
barcode.BarcodeOptions.Margin = 1;
barcode.BarcodeValue = value;


var img = new Image
{
Source = "logo.png",
WidthRequest = 70,
HeightRequest = 70,
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
};

QrCodeSite.Children.Clear();

QrCodeSite.Children.Add(barcode);
QrCodeSite.Children.Add(img);
```

The problem is, maybe my phone (iPhone 6s plus) is too slow, sometimes the logo appears first and after a lag (around 1 second) the QR code is shown. How can I merge the QR code and the logo into one image and then add it to the grid?

Comment: you would need to use an imaging library like SkiaSharp to merge bitmaps

Comment: Here is a small sample to refer merging images with Skiasharp.
https://sreerajpr.com/blogs/xamarin-forms-photo-collage-skiasharp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using **SkiaSharp** to display Image or merge images . Having a look at how to [Display SkiaSharp bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/displaying) to download sample project to research at it.

Based on [Drawing on existing bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing#drawing-on-existing-bitmaps) reference , you can modify it as follow :

```
public partial class MonkeyMoustachePage : ContentPage
{
    SKBitmap monkeyBitmap;

    public MonkeyMoustachePage()
    {
        Title = "Monkey Moustache";

        monkeyBitmap = BitmapExtensions.LoadBitmapResource(GetType(),
            "SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Media.MonkeyFace.png");

        SKBitmap iconImage = BitmapExtensions.LoadBitmapResource(GetType(),
            "SkiaSharpFormsDemos.Media.GooglePlaylogo.png");

        int offset = monkeyBitmap.Width / 2 - iconImage.Width / 2;
        int offsetTop = monkeyBitmap.Height / 2 - iconImage.Height / 2;
        // Create canvas based on bitmap
        using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(monkeyBitmap))
        {
            canvas.DrawBitmap(iconImage, SKRect.Create(offset, offsetTop, iconImage.Width, iconImage.Height));
        }

        // Create SKCanvasView to view result
        SKCanvasView canvasView = new SKCanvasView();
        canvasView.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
        Content = canvasView;

        //save the new image
        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (SKManagedWStream wstream = new SKManagedWStream(memStream))
        {
            monkeyBitmap.Encode(wstream, imageFormat, quality);
            byte[] data = memStream.ToArray();

            // Check the data array for content!

            bool success = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoLibrary>().SavePhotoAsync(data, folder, filename);

            // Check return value for success!
         }
    }

    void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {
        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();
        canvas.DrawBitmap(monkeyBitmap, info.Rect, BitmapStretch.Uniform);
    }
}
```

Then you will see a logo icon will display in original image :

[image]

If you want to save SkiaSharp bitmaps to files , have a look at this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/saving#exploring-the-image-formats

Note: `BitmapExtensions.cs` file is from sample project .By the way , when adding image to project , you need to set **Build ACtion** of image be *Embedded resource* .As follow :

[image]